# Handles clause requires a WithEvents variable defined in the containing type or one of its base type

Tags: vb.net

So I'm very new to coding and especially Visual Basic, and after fidgeting around for a bit with open source code I only seem to have one recurring problem in my current Form1.vb file; Handles clause requires a WithEvents variable defined in the containing type or one of its base type. This is what is looks like:

```
Public Class Form1
Dim Firstnum As Decimal
Dim Secondnum As Decimal
Dim Operations As Integer
Dim Operator_selector As Boolean = False
Private lblHold As Object
Public Property TextBox1 As Object

WithEvents Btn1_click As Button

Private Sub Btn1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btn1.Click
    If TextBox1.Text <> "0" Then
        TextBox1.Text += "1"
    Else
        TextBox1.Text = "1"
    End If
End Sub

Private Sub Btn2_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btn2.Click
    If TextBox1.Text <> "0" Then
        TextBox1.Text += "2"
    Else
        TextBox1.Text = "2"
    End If
End Sub

Private Sub Btn3_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btn3.Click
    If TextBox1.Text <> "0" Then
        TextBox1.Text += "3"
    Else
        TextBox1.Text = "3"
    End If
End Sub

Private Sub Btn4_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btn4.Click
    If TextBox1.Text <> "0" Then
        TextBox1.Text += "4"
    Else
        TextBox1.Text = "4"
    End If
End Sub

Private Sub Btn5_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btn5.Click
    If TextBox1.Text <> "0" Then
        TextBox1.Text += "5"
    Else
        TextBox1.Text = "5"
    End If
End Sub

Private Sub Btn6_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btn6.Click
    If TextBox1.Text <> "0" Then
        TextBox1.Text += "6"
    Else
        TextBox1.Text = "6"
    End If
End Sub

Private Sub Btn7_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btn7.Click
    If TextBox1.Text <> "0" Then
        TextBox1.Text += "7"
    Else
        TextBox1.Text = "7"
    End If
End Sub

Private Sub Btn8_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btn8.Click
    If TextBox1.Text <> "0" Then
        TextBox1.Text += "8"
    Else
        TextBox1.Text = "8"
    End If
End Sub

Private Sub Btn9_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btn9.Click
    If TextBox1.Text <> "0" Then
        TextBox1.Text += "9"
    Else
        TextBox1.Text = "9"
    End If
End Sub

Private Sub Btn0_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btn0.Click
    If TextBox1.Text <> "0" Then
        TextBox1.Text += "0"
    End If
End Sub

Private Sub BtnPoint_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnPoint.Click
    If Not (TextBox1.Text.Contains(".")) Then
        TextBox1.Text += "."
    End If
End Sub

Private Sub BtnClear_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnClear.Click
    TextBox1.Text = "0"
End Sub

Private Sub BtnPlus_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnPlus.Click
    Firstnum = TextBox1.Text
    TextBox1.Text = "0"
    Operator_selector = True
    Operations = 1   'For addition
    lblHold.Text = Firstnum.ToString + "+"

End Sub

Private Sub BtnMinus_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnMinus.Click
    Firstnum = TextBox1.Text
    TextBox1.Text = "0"
    Operator_selector = True
    Operations = 2   'For subtraction
    lblHold.Text = Firstnum.ToString + "-"
End Sub

Private Sub BtnMult_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnMult.Click
    Firstnum = TextBox1.Text
    TextBox1.Text = "0"
    Operator_selector = True
    Operations = 3   'For multiplication
    lblHold.Text = Firstnum.ToString + "*"
End Sub

Private Sub BtnDiv_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnDiv.Click
    Firstnum = TextBox1.Text
    TextBox1.Text = "0"
    Operator_selector = True
    Operations = 4   'For division
    lblHold.Text = Firstnum.ToString + "+"
End Sub

Private Sub BtnEqual_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnEqual.Click
    If Operator_selector = True Then
        Secondnum = TextBox1.Text
        If Operations = 1 Then
            TextBox1.Text = Firstnum + Secondnum
        ElseIf Operations = 2 Then
            TextBox1.Text = Firstnum - Secondnum
        ElseIf Operations = 3 Then
            TextBox1.Text = Firstnum * Secondnum
        Else
            If Secondnum = 0 Then
                TextBox1.Text = "Error!"
            Else
                TextBox1.Text = Firstnum / Secondnum
            End If
            Operator_selector = False
        End If
        lblHold.Text = ""
    End If
End Sub
End Class
```

Now I'm wondering what I have to do to get it right and make this error disappear. I tried using something around the lines of "WithEvents Btn1_click As Button" but it doesn't do anything. It also says "Btn1_click is already declared as 'Private WithEvents Btn1_click As Button' in this class." I'm truly a noob, so please don't throw hardcore coding terms at me but just the simple stuff :P

Many thanks in advance!

Comment: Which line has the error?

Comment: Do you have a button named Btn1?

Comment: There were many lines with an error, and to answer your questions Charles, I didn't have any buttons, that's where I made the mistake :/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `Handles` clause you see on those methods indicates that that method will be executed when the specified event of the object currently assigned to the specified variable is raised.  For example:

```
Private Sub Btn2_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btn2.Click
```

means that the `Btn2_Click` method will be executed when the object assigned to the `btn2` variable raises its `Click` event.  The error message flags this line:

```
Private Sub Btn1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btn1.Click
```

and it's telling you that you have no `btn1` variable declared `WithEvents`.

When you add a control to your form in the designer, it automatically adds a variable with the specified name and declares it `WithEvents`.  You can see that variable if you open the designer code file, which you can access via the Solution Explorer if you click the Show All Files button first.  You can declare your own variables `WithEvents` but this:

```
WithEvents Btn1_click As Button
```

is not using the correct name for a start and it is also useless because it doesn;t have anything assigned to it.  You'd need to create a `Button` object, assign it to the variable and add it to the form, which you haven't done.

The solution would be to simply add a `Button` to the form with that name.

Comment: Thank you jmcilhinney such a simple and understandable answer!